# Stored Procedure to Insert data from a particular timestamp into a temp table and truncate the main table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a set of tables (`_del` tables) that keep track of all the deleted data. I want to copy the records with a timestamp of today and later from these tables into temporary tables. After that I want to truncate the `_del` table. Can someone help me with a stored procedure for the above logic.

Answer (score 0):

What database are you using?  To copy from a single table into another table where a particular column's date is greater than now you could use this:

SQL Server:

```
INSERT INTO MyTempTable1 (Column1, Column2, Colu...)
    SELECT Column1, Column2, Colu...
      FROM _delTable1
     WHERE MyDateColumn > GetDate();

TRUNCATE TABLE _delTable1;
```

MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO MyTempTable1 (Column1, Column2, Colu...)
    SELECT Column1, Column2, Colu...
      FROM _delTable1
     WHERE MyDateColumn > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();

TRUNCATE TABLE _delTable1;
```

If you want to dynamically build the queries for each table that begins with _del then you could loop through the tables and build queries up and execute them - but it depends on what database you are using and even what version.

Another option (depending on what you want to do) is to just delete the data older than today (now or the start of today).

To get the start of today you could do this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, GETDATE()), -1)
```

If you want to use that just replace the GetDate() or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() with it (in brackets).

Comment: I am using sql server database . I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 version. And also I want to write the queries in a storedprocedure and a new table temp table should be created for each _del table with the same schema so that i can insert data into the temp table. I want this to be dynamic.Can you please reply to this with a stored procedure.I dont have any datecolumn in any of the tables.Is there a way i could know the time stamp of each record? Thanks

Comment: If you don't have a date column, you cannot tell the date of the record. And no we aren;t going to write a complex stored proc for you. YOu need to do the work yourself once we point the way.